# jQuery Datatable: Number of matching records by using search()

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm searching my datatable

with the following statement:

```
var dataTable =  $(#dt).DataTable().search("searchpattern");
dataTable.draw();
```

So everything is fine and the datatable is just showing entries that matchs to the searchpattern.

But how i can determine, how many entries are matching to the pattern?

I've tried the following:

```
dataTable.rows().nodes().length;
```

but returned is always the number of all records and not the count of matching records. Thanks for your help in advise!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this, as per [get filtered rows](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/214/how-to-get-searched-or-filtered-data/p1):

> dataTable.$('tr', {"filter":"applied"}).length;

Answer (score 9):

Since DataTables 1.10 , using `dataTable.page.info()` looks the best way to get current info (after processing/ search/ reload).

So..

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var info = table.page.info();

console.log(info);
```

result :

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 6,
    "start": 10,
    "end": 20,
    "length": 10,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsDisplay": 57,
    "serverSide": false
}
```

`info.recordsDisplay` is what you asking for. ref: [page.info() at dataTables API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect for my scenario where I set deferRender to true on my DataTable since it's possible that we display 30,000+ rows. The accepted answer didn't work for my scenario since some of my rows weren't rendered yet due to deferRender. However, recordsDisplay had the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
...
var total_row_count = dataTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
var filtered_row_count = dataTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay();
console.log(total_row_count + " total rows filtered down to " + filtered_row_count);
```

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2278/how-to-get-number-of-rows